# Python: NIPY - nitime.algorithm - multi_taper_csd not being speed up by Parallelization

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, time-series, threadpool, nipy

I have a windowed time series, and I want to regress a value for each window of the time series. I considered this process highly parallelizable so I use the following code:

```
def global_analysis(self, y0:np.ndarray[np.ndarray,np.ndarray], y1:np.ndarray[np.ndarray,np.ndarray],
                    z:np.ndarray, f:np.ndarray,
                    local_function,
                    delta=3.914e-3, window=39.14e-3):`

""" Computes some analysis between two signals in a given window over a length
    
    :param y0           (np.array)      : first signal  [P,S] (used as reference)
    :param y1           (np.array)      : second signal [P,S]
    :param z            (np.ndarray)    : length array    [m]
    :param f            (np.array)      : frequency array [GHz]

    :param local_function (function): function which will compute some operation for each window
    
    :optional delta     (float)       : distance between sensors centers [m]
    :optional window    (float)       : length of the sensors [m]

    :returns output (np.array)      : array with computed signal at each window in a sequence
"""

# Delta and window from meters to number of points
dz = z[1]-z[0] # distance increment
delta  = round(delta/dz)
window = round(window/dz)

# Re-define the window variable (is easier for the rest of the code)
window = round(window/2)

# Get the total number of points
n_points = y0.shape[1]

# Split the whole points into steps
steps = range(window,n_points-window+1,delta)

##### Compute analysis #####

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor: 
    output = list(executor.map(lambda i: process_window(i, y0, y1, z, window, f, local_function), steps))
    executor.shutdown() 
    
return np.array(output)
```

And the function to process each window is

```
def process_window(i, y0, y1, z, window, f, local_function):

    yy0 = np.array([y0[0, i - window:i + window], y0[1, i - window:i + window]])
    yy1 = np.array([y1[0, i - window:i + window], y1[1, i - window:i + window]])
    zz = np.array(z[i - window:i + window])

    return float(local_function(yy0, yy1, zz, f))
```

I'm using different local_functions to get different values for the windowed time-series. I usually use as the local_function the function "A", which consists of a series of numpy operations, and the results are good, I obtain a 10x faster execution. However, when I try to use as the local_function the function "P",  which consists of a series of numpy operations PLUS a nitime (another library) multitapered cross spectral density calculations, I cannot speed up the execution, actually I get a 50% slower execution. WHY? Which are the requirements for my local_function to be parallelized properly?

I tried different parallelization functions as ProcessPoolExecutor.

I also tried to dive into the nitime library and I found that the function "tridisolve" from the utils module must be redefined in python because the cythonized version is not importable.